# Unix Commands are not working

Tags: unix, environment-variables

New to Unix, I recently tried to add a `$PATH` variable in Unix in order to debug my android sdk. I looked up online the directions and tried to follow them as thoroughly as possible. What ended up happening is that my basic commands no longer work (e.g. `ls`, `man`, `cd` etc...) I get a message stating "-bash: ls: command not found". I am not sure what I might have done. Maybe I might have wrote over the original file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably overwrote your PATH variable instead of appending to it.  My PATH variable on my computer right now (Ubuntu 11.10) looks like this:

rvoliva@bobby-ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

I'm guessing yours doesn't have any of those bin folders in it at the moment.  When you use export to modify your PATH, make sure you append to it:

export PATH=/new/path/location/dir:$PATH

Comment: Yes. I believe that is what I did. When I echo $PATH it shows a path pointing to my Android SDK folder, which obviously isn't the correct directory. How can I return my PATH variable to the default? I would like to have Unix working normally again.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: If you modified your startup scripts ($HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.bash_profile, $HOME/.profile), then back out whatever changes you made.  Then launch a new terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

You defined `PATH` such that it doesn't include basic directories like `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. Use absolute paths to an editor (i.e., `/usr/bin/vi` and add those back in. You probably want to be doing something like

```
export PATH=/my/android/thingy:$PATH
```

If you leave off the `:$PATH` at the end, you're ignoring the system default, which prevents you from finding all the usual utilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot I managed to use your help to solve this issue.